# How to make slide out menu with out storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift

First thing that I want to tell is **I DONT HAVE A STORYBOARD**. I want to make a slide out menu. I did a slide out menu with storyboard, from this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/), but in my real project I **have no storyboard**. I'm using `SWRevealViewController`.

I import `SWRevealViewController` to my project. Can you help me? I am stopped by this problem, I have to solve this

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a storyboard?

Comment: I delete storyboard, I'm doing everything programmatically, by using SnapKit, what i should do?

Comment: If you're sure about ditching storyboards then okay. They do give you a lot of power with AutoLayout though. Try following the instructions and look through the tutorials of the framework: https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController. Storyboards are not a requirement for SWRevealViewController.

Comment: Actually, this one in Objective-C and I'm using Swift

Comment: That's totally fine. The languages are comparable. In fact Swift is build on top of Objective-C, so you should have no trouble transcribing it with a little practice.

Comment: You can still use storyboard with snapkit. You just create the viewcontrollers in storyboard so they are instantiated that way, and then use snapkit for laying out the contents of those viewcontrollers. 
However, if you're using SnapKit because you can't be bothered to teach yourself auto layout, you are doing yourself a disservice, IMHO...

Comment: How i can return my storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achive it by using BTSimpleSideMenu

https://github.com/balram3429/BTSimpleSideMenu

It is in objective c, but using bridge you can achieve it easily.

Just import in bridge file.
 #import "BTSimpleSideMenuClass.h"

then

```
var objBTSimpleSideMenuClass = BTSimpleSideMenuClass()

// noOfItems - will be your array with title and image

func setupSideOutMenu()
{
    GLOBAL.sharedInstance.writeToLog(optionalvalue: "")

    objBTSimpleSideMenuClass.delegate = self

    let ary : NSMutableArray = []

    for var i = 0; i < noOfItems.count; i++
    {
        let item = BTSimpleMenuItemClass.init(title: noOfItems[i].valueForKey("ItemName") as! String, image: noOfItems[i].valueForKey("ItemImage")) { (success, item) -> Void in

        }

        ary.addObject(item)
    }

    let swiftArray = ary as NSArray

    objBTSimpleSideMenuClass =  BTSimpleSideMenuClass.init(item: swiftArray as [AnyObject], addToViewController: self)

}
```